# How to assign values for dummy variables in sas

Tags: sas, proc

I have a dataset which includes cities , state and claims and premium

```
 City       state       Claims       Model
 Mumbai    Karnataka    200000      Honda city
 Bangalore Maharastra   190000      Ford
 Kochi      Kerala      150000      honda city
```

I have created dummy variables for model. I want to impute values of claim in the dummy variable. Example is given below. I want my dataset to look like this.

```
 City       state       Claims       Model        HondaCity    Ford
 Mumbai    Karnataka    200000      Honda city     200000      0
 Bangalore Maharastra   190000      Ford           0           190000
 Kochi      Kerala      150000      honda city     150000      0
```

instead of 0/1 dummy, I want to impute claim values to model variable. My aim is to predict the risk based premium. How can I do that?

Comment: You said you have already created 0/1 dummy variables in your dataset?  Then you can multiply those by Claims to get what you want, right?

Comment: you mean to say I can use 
if Model='Honda city' then HondaCity=1*(claim);
but how do I get the value for Claim?

Comment: Sorry, not understanding what yo want.  If you have a data set like you showed, then you already have the variable named Claims.  If you have already created dummy variables named HondaCity and Ford that are coded 0/1 like you said, then all you need to do is HondaCity=HondaCity*claims;

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need help with this (or for future reference), the following code converts the first dataset into the second one:

```
proc sql;
    create table new_table as
    select 
        a.*
        ,case when upper(model) = "HONDA CITY" then claims else 0 end as HondaCity
        ,case when upper(model) = "FORD" then claims else 0 end as Ford
    from old_table as a;
quit;
```